# C++ global variables across DLLs

Tags: c++, windows

I wrote something to simulate the getopt.h library for a Windows application, and part of this is a global variable.  This worked fine when I compiled the program as a single application; however, when I split off the getopt library and linked against it, my program started getting segfaults. Investigating this, it seems that accessing the variable from outside the DLL doesn't work and returns an invalid pointer; is there anything I can do to fix this?

Edit:If I enter a function in the DLL in the debugger, the variable has the correct value - acessing it directly from the application gives a different value.

Comment: Could you print out the address of the variable from both inside the DLL and from outside. This is to find out whether you have one or two copies of the variable.

Comment: In addition, how is the variable set up? Is it a function returning a pointer, an externally exposed pointer, just a variable...?

Comment: It's just an externally exposed pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's probably happening is that you haven't setup the `dllexport/dllimport` correctly. The result is that you're ending up with different copies of the same variable. (one in the DLL and one outside)

Within the DLL, you need to compile with `dllexport` to expose the variable to the client application.

Then in the client application, you need to declare the same variable as `dllimport`. Then it will link against the one that's in the DLL.

This is slightly unfortunate because the same headers are usually used for the DLL and the client. So the usual work-around is this:

```
#ifdef COMPILE_DLL
#define DLL_EXPORT  __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_EXPORT  __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

EDIT:

Can you confirm whether or not you have two copies of the same variable? Try printing out the addresses from both inside the DLL and from outside.

Comment: DLL import/export won't help with getting an invalid pointer from the DLL. They control symbols being externally visible, they don't actually change the variable itself.

Comment: @peachykeen: How do you know the problem isn't that there are different copies because it isn't setup correctly? The pointer is being written correctly in the DLL but the client application is (unintentionally) reading it's own (invalid) copy because they aren't merged (when they're supposed to be).

Comment: That is possible, depending on the variable type and how things are set up. I'll remove my down vote, though I think some OP clarification would be helpful. *Edit:* Seems I can't remove unless you edit the answer.

Comment: @peachykeen: I made my edit, and asked to confirm if there are one or two copies of the variable.

Answer (score 3):

Consider adding a function to your DLL that returns the value of the variable.